# Swift image view scrollable without using UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, scrollable

Is there a way to make an imageView scrollable without using a UIScrollView. If I zoom my picture I can't scroll, that's what I'm trying to solve

Comment: Use UICollectionView instead of scollview.

Comment: You can try UIPanGesture

Comment: Isn't there an other way without using scrollview and collectionview?

Comment: with out scrollview you can't scroll